# Thread.sleep() optimization for small sleep intervals

Tags: java, scala, jvm

I am writing a library that involves a caller-defined temporal resolution. In the implementation, this value ends up being an interval some background thread will sleep before doing some housekeeping and going back to sleep again. I am allowing this resolution to be as small as 1 millisecond, which translates to `Thread.sleep(1)`. My hunch is that that may be more wasteful and less precise than busy-waiting for 1 ms. If that's the case;

1. Should I fall back to busy-waiting for small enough (how small) time intervals?
2. Does anyone know if the JVM is already doing this optimization anyway and I don't need to do anything at all?

Comment: A busy wait for 1ms will take millions of instructions on a modern processor, so very unlikely to be more efficient than an OS wait.

Comment: Do you need millisecond accuracy for housekeeping threads?

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for a higher level library like **cats-effect** instead of sleeping thread directly you would use fibers.

Comment: Also look at LockSupport#parkNanos which has more fine-grained resolution and minimizes the stress put on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy to test:

```
public class Test {

    static int i = 0;
    static long[] measurements = new long[0x100];
    
    static void report(long value) {
        measurements[i++ & 0xff] = value;
        if (i > 10_000) {
            for (long m : measurements) {
                System.out.println(m);
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    static void sleepyWait() throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            long before = System.nanoTime();
            Thread.sleep(1);
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            report(now - before);
        }                   
    }
    
    static void busyWait() {
        while (true) {
            long before = System.nanoTime();
            long now;
            do {
                now = System.nanoTime();
            } while (before + 1_000_000 >= now);
            report(now - before);
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        busyWait();
    }
}
```

Run on my windows system, this shows that busyWait has microsecond accuracy, but fully uses one CPU core.

In contrast, sleepyWait causes no measurable CPU load, but only achieves millisecond accuracy (often taking as much as 2 ms to fire, rather than the 1 ms requested).

At least on windows, this is therefore a straightforward tradeoff between accuracy and CPU use.

It's also worth noting that there are often alternatives to running a CPU at full speed obsessively checking the time. In many cases, there is some other signal you could be waiting for, and offering an API that focuses on time-based resolution may steer the users of your API in a bad direction.

Comment: Thanks, @meriton for this. Your result seems to suggest that the precision of the task scheduler on the Windows OS is a few millis. That's actionable -- I should disallow millisecond-grained resolution on Windows. I will run your test on other OSs as well.